# Find the lowest common multiple of a range of numbers

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript assignment and am having some trouble understanding the code. I am working with this code, and it works but I want to break it down further to truly understand what is going on. I have commented out the parts that I do understand, but have left questions on some of the more difficult parts for me.

```js
//Finding the Least Common Denominator with a Recursive Euclidean Algorithm 
//GCD = Biggest Number that is divides into both evenly
function gcd(a, b) {
  return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : Math.abs(a); //Ternary Operator to run if b is valid
  //Is this ternary operator only checking if the variable b exists?
}

//Least Common Multiple = Smallest number that is divisible by both numbers
//Euclidean Algorithm
function scm(a, b) {
  return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
}

//Iterate through each part of the array to find the LCM overall
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort();
  result = 1;
  for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
    //I am not quite sure what is happening in this for loop.        
    result = scm(result, scm(result, i));
  }
  return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + smallestCommons([1, 5]) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The ternary operator is checking if the variable `b` is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Read the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) docs and, please, research your questions before asking here.

Comment: The first one is just shortcut for if/else. And its using recursion (call to the function itself) to find the GCD.

Comment: Is 60 really the LCM of [1,5]? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`Is this ternary operator only checking if the variable b exists?`

The notation is just for checking that it is a truthy value, as `Blazemonger` commented. However, it is specifically meant to stop the recursion when the base condition (i.e. `b = 0`) is met.

`I am not quite sure what is happening in this for loop.`

The loop evaluates the LCM of all the numbers from `arr[0]` to `arr[1]`, taking one number at a time. That is done to avoid overrunning the integer limit in case the numbers are large.

The evaluation is based on the fact that for three integers a, b and c, `LCM(a, b, c) = LCM(LCM(a, b), c)` and `LCM(1, x) = x`. So at every step, the loop evaluates the LCM of the processed part and the current item (i.e. `i`).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my answer as comments below. Changed some names and fixed the wrong algorithm.

```
/*
When b is not zero, null, undefined, NaN (not a number), or false, then compute greatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b). Otherwise return the absoute value of a.
This will make sense if you step through it with an example. Let's try to find the greatest common divisor of 6 and 9, which we know is 3.

1. a=6, b=9
2. a=9, b=6
3. a=6, b=3
4. a=3, b=0
5. B is falsy!
return absoulte value of a, which is 3.
*/
function greatestCommonDivisor(a, b) {
    return b ? greatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b) : Math.abs(a);
}

function leastCommonMultipleOfTwo(a, b) {
    return (a * b) / greatestCommonDivisor(a, b);
}

/*
No wonder you were confused. The algorithm they gave you was wrong. I fixed it below. Let's look at that with an example.

Let's say we're trying to find the least common multiple of [5, 2, 9]. Logically we know it's 90. (The wrong algorithm gave 60).

The algorithm below takes the array elements one at a time, and finds the LCM of it and whatever LCM we've calculated so far.
Initially we start with calculatedLCM = 1 to get the algorithm started.

1. we look at arr[0], which is 5
calculatedLCM = leastCommonMultipleOfTwo(1,5)
calculatedLCM = 5

2. we look at arr[1], which is 2
calculatedLCM = leastCommonMultipleOfTwo(5,2)
calculatedLCM = 10

3. we look at arr[2], which is 9
calculatedLCM = leastCommonMultipleOfTwo(10,9)
calculatedLCM = 90

*/

function leastCommonMultiple(arr) {
    calculatedLCM = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        calculatedLCM = leastCommonMultipleOfTwo(calculatedLCM, arr[i]);
    }
    return calculatedLCM;
}

console.log(leastCommonMultiple([5, 2, 9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

> > Is this ternary operator only checking if the variable b exists?

No, it is checking if it is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy): *a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).*

If `b` is not specified its value will be `undefined` which is a falsy value. In the code provided it is actually checking if the value is 0 due to the recursion using the modulo: `gcb(b, a % b)`.

> > I am not quite sure what is happening in this for loop.

First, it might help to break it down like this:

```
var res;
// `arr[0]` is the first value which is assigned to `i`
// The loop will iterate until `i` is equal to
//  the second value `arr[1]`
for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
  res = scm(result, i);
  result = scm(result, res);
}
```

And then manually step through it with your input `[1, 5]`:

1. With: `result === 1; i === 1; arr[1] === 5;`

   `res = scm(1, 1) // res === 1`

   `result = scm(1, 1) // result === 1`
2. With: `result === 1; i === 2; arr[1] === 5;`

   `res = scm(1, 2) // res === 2`

   `result = scm(1, 2) // result === 2`
3. With: `result === 2; i === 3; arr[1] === 5;`

   `res = scm(2, 3) // res === 6`

   `result = scm(2, 6) // result === 6`
4. With: `result === 6; i === 4; arr[1] === 5;`

   `res = scm(6, 4) // res === 12`

   `result = scm(6, 12) // result === 12`
5. With: `result === 12; i === 5; arr[1] === 5;` **LAST LOOP**

   `res = scm(12, 5) // res === 60`

   `result = scm(12, 60) // result === 60`

A few observations to be made:

- Is 60 really the LCM of [1, 5]?
- Why make two calls to scm if both the inner `scm` call and the outer `scm` call return the same value?

I would guess the code doesn't work as intended. :)

Comment: That does not answer all the questions specified by @Eric Park, so its not valid for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is a recursive function (a function in which you call the same function). It will call itself until it is called with value b being equal to 0. The ternary operator is there for that. As long as it is not 0 the test evaluates to TRUE, hence doing the first instruction, recursion with the manipulation you see. Whenever a%b will be 0, meaning a is divisible by b, it will actually be the last recursive call, the ternary test will evaluate to FALSE and returning value of a.

The second function just make use of this first one in order to use a mathematical formula to find smallest common multiple.

The third function makes use of the second one to find scm of a series of numbers, the initial range, and the loop is doing exactly that, variable i iterating from lower boundary to higher boundary of the range.